# Ошибка при компиляции c++!

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "UDPSocket.h"

class Server
{
private:
    UDPSocket* socket;
    std::thread* networkthread;
    int port;
public:
    Server(int port);
    void handlePacket();
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чём же дело.

```
UDPSocket.h

#ifndef _SOCKET_H_
#define _SOCKET_H_

#include <exception>
#include <mutex>

#ifdef __unix__
#   include <errno.h>
#   include <sys/types.h>
#   include <sys/socket.h>
#   include <sys/un.h>
#   include <netinet/in.h>
#   include <netdb.h>
#   include <arpa/inet.h>
#   include <unistd.h>
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1
#else
#   include <winsock2.h>
#   include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#   include <windows.h>
#   ifdef _MSC_VER
#       pragma comment( lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#   endif
#endif

#define DEFAULT_PORT 19132
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1048 * 2
#include "./BinaryStream.h"
#include "Server.h"
#include <thread>
    class UDPSocket
    {
    private:
        bool isStarted;

#ifdef WIN32
        SOCKET sock;
        WSAData data;
#else
        int sock;
#endif

    public:
        bool isRuning;


    public:
        UDPSocket();
        UDPSocket(short port);
        UDPSocket(std::string ip);
        UDPSocket(std::string ip, short port, Server *server);
        ~UDPSocket();

        bool bind(std::string ip, short port);

        void receive();
        //int send(Packet*);

        void close();
        Server* server;
    };
#endif
```

Comment: Совершенно неизвестно, что у вас в `UDPSocket.h` - например, включен ли файл `<thread>`. Может, вы там еще каких-то ошибок навставляли...

Comment: Если я не ошибся с подсчетом строк ,то компилятор не опознает тип std::thread, то есть (как и предположил Harry) Вы не подключили <thread>

Comment: добавил UDPSocket.h

Comment: Все же попробуйте включить <thread> в файл с определением класса Server

Comment: Хотя с архитектурой у Вас как-то странно... в сервере поле UDP-сокета, а в сокете поле сервера... Вы уверены, что все правильно сделали? Честно говоря, я не могу понять, зачем такое нужно, тем более, что может привести к зацикливанию вызовов.

Answer (score 3):

`Server.h` включает `UDPSocket.h`, который включает `Server.h`. A `Server.h` не имеет защиту от многоразового включения и `class Server` определяется несколько раз подряд. Что бы решить проблему нужно:

1. Добавить защиту от многоразового включения в `Server.h`
2. Не зацикливать файлы (уберите `include` этих файлов)
3. Добавить обьявления (не определения) классов (перед классом `Server` напишите `class UDPSocket;` , а перед классом `UDPSocket` напишите `class Server;`
4. В файлы реализаций подключать оба файла (и `Server.h`, и `UDPSocket.h`)

Comment: и как мне сделать правильно?

Comment: P.S. Ну и подключите thread в Server.h